# How do i connect to an Ethereum node?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I setup an Ethereum light node on a VPS using Geth, and i'm running it using:

```
nohup geth --syncmode "light" --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --ws --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8080 &
```

Now from my local laptop i would like to use this node to perform web3 queries to the Etherum blockchain. I'm using python but i tried to do the same using Web3js too and the output is the same:

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://MY-VPS-IP:8080'))
print(w3.isConnected())
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
False
```

Which means, i'm assuming, that the node is not accessible from outside the vps where i hosted it. How can i access it from outside? In theory the command i used should work, and i also made sure to have port 80 open. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Use `telnet` command to test if you can connect the port from your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

The command you write is old and not fully correct use this:

```
geth --syncmode "light" --ws --ws.addr "specific IP" --http --http.addr "specific IP"
```

Comment: Note that binding RPC ports to all public IPs to your Ethereum node, what `0.0.0.0` effectively does, is a bad idea as your node will get a lot of malicious traffic. It is only recommend for people who know what they are doing. Instead, bind RPC to a specific IP that it *not* exposed to Internet.

Comment: yes you are right, its just an example i have to edit my answer thanks a lot